# Define the SonarQube project properties in Ant build

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have all my sonar properties defined in build.xml like

```
"sonar.jdbc.url" 
"sonar.jdbc.driverClassName" 
"sonar.jdbc.username" 
"sonar.jdbc.password" 
"sonar.host.url"
```

but I don't want to define username and password in my build.xml. If I remove that, where should I define these properties.

Answer (score 0):

You don't list your version, but with 5.6 the current LTS, you no longer need to provide database credentials. Just the token of a user authorized to analyze the project (assuming Anyone can't).

Comment: we have sonar version 4.5.5